# Mercurial на CentOS 8 по http отдает ошибку 500 internal server error

Tags: apache, cgi, mercurial, centos8

мужчины! Подскажите по поводу Меркуриал. Версия Меркуриал 5.3.1. Система Centos 8, Apache (виртуальные хосты). Меркуриал локально работает, коммиты создаёт. По http отдает ошибку 500 «internal server error». В логах - end of script output before headers hgweb.cgi

При запуске cgi сервера из папки с репой по команде «python3 -m http.server —cgi» хотя бы начинает работать клон (пуш/пулл и т.д. естественно не работают) и в браузере вмдно папки.

Пробовал настроить через mod_wsgi - эффект тот же. Пробовал на виртуалке поднять на centos 7, Меркуриал более старой версии в репе, кажется 3. Эффект тот же.

Если нужны какие-то конфиги - ноу проблем, только скажите.

SElinux отключен. Если это важно, для установки Меркуриал сначала установил tk.

Подскажите хотя бы, в какую сторону смотреть? Идёт третий день войны.

Answer (score 0):

Не срабатывал CGI   и FCGI. 
В хосте в директори прописывал
Require all granted
Перезапустил Апач - не работало. 
Перезапустил весь сервер - заработало.
Но все же сначала пробуйте перезапускать Апач